# how to find the undesirable formatting in a presentation/slides such as bold or Symbol font

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, formatting, libreoffice, find-and-replace

My manager told me he think in some places of my presentation file he noticed inappropriate formats such as bold and Symbol font. Is there an easy way, preferably free like in free beer way to search the document for specific formatting?

I tried LibreOffice 7 Impress but do not find any format based search

The presentation is in Google Slides, but I suspect that a desktop app might have more search option, so ask in superuser rather than

Comment: should I cross-post to webapps or it is some "bad practice"

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - Also, asking for software recommendations tends not to go down well, even if they are *technically* allowed.

Comment: It is possible to select all text in the in the *View > Outline* mode, right-click, and *Clear direct formatting*. *Caution:* this might have undesirable consequences, so save to another filename rather than overwriting the original. Of course, *all* valid formatting then needs to be reapplied.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Which version do you find this command in?  I don't have it in Windows PPT 2021 and, honestly, don't recall ever having seen it in any prior version.  But I very seldom look at, much less use, the web or Mac versions.  Also, even if it's there it will only affect text in title or body placeholders. Text added as text boxes, or in charts, smartart, notes text and several other places won't be touched.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, Sorry, I left out one *very* important point: 1. Load the presentation into LibreOffice Impress. 2. Change view to *Outline Mode*. 3. Select all text. 4. Right click and *Clear direct formatting*. 5. Save as PPT(x) under different name.

Comment: Thanks, I think I successfully corrected formatting manually

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Aha. That explains why I couldn't find that command in PowerPoint. Thanks.